# Ruby on Rails - Issue with encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While inserting data in a db (sqlite3) I get following error

> Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xF0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8):

In database.yml file, I have provided the encoding as UTF-8

```
development:
<<: *default
database: db/development.sqlite3
encoding: utf8
```

Even sqlite is configured to accept UTF-8 (PRAGMA encoding returns UTF-8).

Still the query is rolling back -

```
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "chat_data_regulars" ("username",    "chat_timestamp", "name", "sent_text", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["username", "a5fbf8bb6fea32fbbcc566c744592136"], ["chat_timestamp", "2016-05-14 04:12:16.942722"], ["name", "Tushar Saurabh"], ["sent_text", "You gave your mentee critical feedback"], ["created_at", "2016-05-14 04:12:33.308923"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-14 04:12:33.308923"]]
   (12.6ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16416ms (ActiveRecord: 14.5ms)

   Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xF0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8):
```

Comment: are you trying to add a new record from a model? if so, i think you need to add `#encoding: utf-8` at the very top of you model file

Comment: @jhonquintero, yes I am adding it through model. I added **#encoding: utf-8** but I am getting same error.

Comment: What encoding do your HTML pages have? It would be best it they were in UTF-8 too. If they are, can you provide the full stack trace? Possibly even after removing backtrace silencers in the `backtrace_silencers.rb` initializer? And what ruby + rails version do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try to force the conversion to UTF before storing to the database.  This code will convert the original string, replacing invalid or undefined characters:

```
string.encode!("UTF-8", invalid: :replace, undef: :replace).force_encoding("utf-8") }
```

See this information on [String#encode](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-encode) for more information.

If your encodings are matched, and you still have this issue, you can simply strip those non-ASCII characters from the strings with this gsub call:

```
x.map {|text| text.gsub!(/[^\001-\176]+/, "") }
```

The regex will remove any characters that are between ASCII code 1 (octal 001) and ASCII code 126 (octal 176). This effectively scrubs the string of any non-ASCII characters (and ASCII 0).

If you require "extended ASCII" for use with an international character set, such as ISO-8859 character set or Windows 1252, or even specific Unicode characters, you can extend the range to include those characters by changing the digits to include those characters.